# the equivalent method of get_eval in Selenium Ruby Webdriver

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, webdriver

I have the below code that use "get_eval" method well in Selenium RC:

```
@selenium.get_eval("var window = this.browserbot.getUserWindow(); var
   map = window.F1.Maker.current_map; var layers = map.getLayers();
   layers[0].guid");
```

Anybody please guide me the equivalent method with "get_eval()" in Selenium Ruby Webdriver ? Much appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`driver.execute_script` will serve the same purpose.

Comment: thanks much, so could you please guide me more how to replace lines of code in my examples: var window = this.browserbot.getUserWindow()  to the same codes in Ruby Webdriver? many thanks.

Comment: Anybody please guide me the equivalent code of "var window = this.browserbot.getUserWindow()" in Selenium RC to Selenium Ruby Webdriver ? Thanks much.

Comment: I got the error: Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError: TypeError: this.browserbot is undefined when use the script you suggested: driver.execute_script("var window = this.browserbot.getUserWindow(); var map = window.F1.Maker.current_map; var layers = map.getLayers(); layers[0].guid;"); So I think that we need to replace this.browserbot.getUserWindow() to something equivalent in Ruy Webdriver. Could you please suggest me a solution for this ? Thank you very much.

Comment: I replaced the code in two ways as your suggestion: 1. selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow() and 2. selenium.browserbot.window. However, I got the error with both ways: "Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError: ReferenceError: Selenium is not defined" Could you please give me another solution ? Much appreciate.

Comment: If nothing worked,Be chilax and try this only : driver.execute_script("var map = window.F1.Maker.current_map; var layers = map.getLayers(); layers[0].guid;");..No need to getUserWindow.